# Force XML using XSD to mimic radio button behavior

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an application that has 6 radio buttons in a group on a form. Settings on this form can be exported into XML and re-imported. Before commencing the re-import session I want to validate the XML file using an XSD, to make sure that if the user edited the XML, he did it right. I plan to do it using an XSD if possible.

Since radio buttons on the GUI must have a single buutton and only a single button selected I want to mimic this behavior using an XSD. I want to receive XSD schema errors if there are multiple options set to True in the XML or there are none.

Is it possible to achieve this using XSD, or do I need to code this type of validation in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerations naturally mirror the exclusive nature of radio buttons and will work in both XSD 1.0 and 1.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="RadioButton">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="v1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="v2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="v3"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="v4"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="v5"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="v6"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```